# Function for creating a graph of levels using networkx library

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to create a function where in it will loop twice or thrice depending on the levels mentioned by me for creating a graph using networkx library.

If a person knows skill Python then he knows AWS and Hadoop too [level 1]

Then I want to search skills related to AWS and Hadoop [level 2].

Please help me to create a function with a exception handling wherein it is possible that the related skills do not have their related skills in the data.

[this is how pairs look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r74MY.png)

This is the standard function I created for level 1.

```
def network(pair, skill):
  skil=[]
  related_skil=[]
  for line in pair[:306444]:
    s, r = line[0], line[1]
    #print(s)
    if (s == skill):
      skil.append(s)
      related_skil.append(r)
      
  skill=pd.DataFrame(columns=["skills"],data=skil)
  relat_skil=pd.DataFrame(columns=["related_skills"],data=related_skil)

  df=pd.concat([skill,relat_skil],axis=1)
  
  G=nx.Graph()
  G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'skills','related_skills')

  figure(figsize=(12,10))
  a = nx.draw(G,node_color='red',with_labels=True)

  return a

network(pair=pairs, skill='Python')
```

where pair is a list zip file of skills and related skills pairs=list(zip(skill,related skill))

Comment: Would be possible to add a small set of example data (`pair` and `skill`), as well as the expected results? Also, what does level 2 mean here; wouldn't that imply that you need a mapping from person to skill to related skill? I do not see person mentioned in the function.

Comment: There is no person only skill and related skill mapping. If my base skill is Python its related skill could be AWS, Machine Learning, Big Data [ this is level 1 ], now in the same graph I want to see related skills of AWS, Machine Learning, Big data [ this is level 2]. I am adding pairs and an example of expected result please take a  look at it and help me with the solution. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

The `networkx` library contains probably all you need to solve the question

> Given a skill A, is skill B a related skill?

We'll assume that related skills are directional (knowing Python might
lead to knowing AWS, but not vice versa). For this, we'll use the
directed graph model.

We can also use shortest path length to model relatedness level and
use that to color and layer the output graph.

In the program below, unrelated skills are removed to simplify the
graph: Prolog is not related to Python (arrows are wrong direction),
C and Embedded systems are not connected to the Python skill graph.

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def skill_rel(skill, rel_skill):
    if skill not in G:
        print(f"{skill} skill no longer in graph")
        return
    if rel_skill not in G:
        print(f"{rel_skill} skill no longer in graph")
        return
    related = nx.has_path(G, skill, rel_skill)
    print(f"{skill} skill and relation to {rel_skill}",
          related, end=' ')
    if related:
        print('level',
              nx.shortest_path_length(G, skill, rel_skill))

def level_rel(skill, rel_skill):
    related = nx.has_path(G, skill, rel_skill)
    if related:
        return nx.shortest_path_length(G, skill, rel_skill)
    else:
        return 999

pairs = [('Python', 'AWS'),
         ('Python', 'Machine Learning'),
         ('Python', 'Big Data'),
         ('AWS', 'Hadoop'),
         ('C', 'Embedded Systems'),
         ('Prolog', 'Artificial Intelligence'),
         ('Machine Learning', 'Deep Learning'),
         ('Machine Learning', 'Artificial Intelligence')]
skill = 'Python'
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(pairs)
# Remove unrelated skills (>= level 5)
unrelatedness = 5
unrelated = [node for node in G if level_rel(skill, node) >= unrelatedness]
G.remove_nodes_from(unrelated)
# Group/color nodes based on relatedness to use shell graph drawing
nlevel = [(node, level_rel(skill, node)) for node in G]
g1 = itertools.groupby(sorted(nlevel, key=lambda x: x[1]), key=lambda x: x[1])
shells = tuple(tuple(x[0] for x in g) for _,g in g1)
pos = nx.shell_layout(G, nlist=shells)
colors = [lvl[1] for lvl in nlevel]
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, node_color=colors, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
skill_rel(skill, 'Hadoop')
skill_rel('Prolog', 'Hadoop')
print('Level 2 related skills from', skill, shells[2])
```

Output graph with levels colored:

[image: Output graph with levels colored]

Output:

```
# Python skill and relation to Hadoop True level 2
# Prolog skill no longer in graph
# Level 2 related skills from Python
# ('Hadoop', 'Artificial Intelligence', 'Deep Learning')
```

Comment: Here related skills of only one skill is possible skill_rel(skill, 'Hadoop'). I want to mention levels how can I modify this code. If I want to draw a graph till level 3 or level 4 how can I do it.  Since I have a whole dataset there can be related skills of all the level 1 skills or the level 2 skills.

Comment: I have 30000 rows of data so I have to mention level for it to break at some point. Please can you modify the solution because my colab is running for past 25 min and still the graph is not achieved.

Comment: According to your pairs. Level 1 is related skills of Python --- AWS, Big data and Machine learning. Level 2 would be related skills of AWS, Big data and Machine learning ---- hadoop, deep learning, artificial intelligence. Level 3 would be related skills of hadoop, deep learning, artificial intelligence. So kindly help me with a code which can break at certain point where we can mention levels.

Comment: Updated with level layering and removal of unrelated and far related skills. I would like to know if this runs quicker in your colab.

Comment: It's probably because the picture is filled with 30,000 labels. Try drawing the network without labels. Also, does `shells[2]` give you a good level 2 list of related skills?

Comment: Yes you can see In the image the last line it's giving related skills but the graph is not according to it...

Comment: How about you try this with a reduced dataset first, let's say 500 pairs? What do you see then? By my calculation, if there's 30,000 nodes drawn on 1 megapixel canvas, with each node 50 pixels big, it still covers the entire page in ink. Or, only graph level 0 and 1. Also, if you like my answer, please accept it as answered and upvote it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235524/discussion-between-sham-and-virtualscooter).

Comment: Yes I did using 500 pairs but what is it doing is it is plotting related skills of all the skills in the data. I asked for level 2 related skills. It has given me related skills till level 3. Basically it doesnt stop at a particular point but connects each skill to other.

Comment: Your solution isn't relevant for the question I asked but its a good solution for directed graphs and finding the shortest path. (have to consider subset of the data for good result.)

Comment: Can you tell me how can I find the shortest path between two nodes. For eg: shortest path between Python and Big data. So it should mention the name of the nodes Python-Machine learning- Deep learning- Spark-Bigdata something like this.